# Java NetBeans Error: run: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated

Tags: java, swing

i have made this tic tac toe game, and apparently there is this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
at java.awt.Frame.setOpacity(Frame.java:960)
at java.awt.Window$1.setOpacity(Window.java:4037)
at com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(AWTUtilities.java:174)
at tictacktoe.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:35)
at tictacktoe.MainForm$19.run(MainForm.java:665)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I use windows 10, netbeans, if that helps, here is my code:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

/*
* MainForm.java
*
* Created on 23 Feb, 2019, 5:46:53 PM
*/

package tictacktoe;

import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;



/**
*
* @author Erfan
*/
public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form MainForm */
public MainForm() {
     try{UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");}
    catch(Exception e){}
    initComponents();       
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this,(float)0.90);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    reset();
}
int[][] pos=new int[3][3];
int cnt,val,a,b,c=1,d=1,diff=1,vs=1;
char let;
String pl1="You",pl2="Computer";
Random rnd=new Random();
boolean turn=true;

void reset()
{
    for (int i=0;i<3 ;i++ )
    {
        for (int j=0;j<3 ;j++ ){pos[i][j]=0;}
    }
    Component[] cmpnt=this.getContentPane().getComponents();
    for(int i=0;i<cmpnt.length;i++)
    {
        if(cmpnt[i] instanceof JLabel)
            ((JLabel) cmpnt[i]).setText("") ;
    }
    cnt=0;
    val=1;
    let='X';
    jLabel10.setText(pl1+" to Play NOW.");
}

boolean play(int l,int m)
{
    if(pos[l][m]==0)
    {
        a=c;b=d;c=l;d=m;
        JLabel ctrl=link(l,m);
        ctrl.setText(String.valueOf(let));
        pos[l][m]=val;
        flip();
        checkwin(l,m,pos[l][m]);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

JLabel link(int l,int m)
{
    if(l==0)
    {
        if(m==0)
                return jLabel1;
        if(m==1)
                return jLabel2;
        if(m==2)
                return jLabel3;
    }
    if(l==1)
    {
        if(m==0)
                return jLabel6;
        if(m==1)
                return jLabel5;
        if(m==2)
                return jLabel4;
    }
    if(l==2)
    {
        if(m==0)
                return jLabel9;
        if(m==1)
                return jLabel8;
        if(m==2)
                return jLabel7;
    }
    return null;
}

void flip()
{
    if(let=='X')
    {
        let = 'O';
        val=4;
        cnt++;
    }
    else
    {
        let = 'X';
        val=1;
        cnt++;
    }
}

void checkwin(int l,int m,int n)
{
    if(cnt==1)
        if(vs==1)
            turn=true;
    if(cnt>4)
    {
        if((pos[l][0]+pos[l][1]+pos[l][2]==n*3)||(pos[0][m]+pos[1][m]+pos[2][m]==n*3))
        {
            cnt=n;
        }
        else
        {
            if((pos[0][0]+pos[1][1]+pos[2][2]==n*3)||(pos[2][0]+pos[1][1]+pos[0][2]==n*3))
            {
                cnt=n;
            }
            else
            {
                if(cnt==9)
                {
                        cnt=0;
                }
            }
        }
        if(cnt==1||cnt==0)
        {
            if(cnt==1)
                declare(pl1+" (Playing X) Wins!");
            if(cnt==0)
                declare("The Game is a Draw!");
            reset();
            if(vs==1)
            if(pl1=="Computer")
            {
                turn=false;
                compplay(val);
            }
            else
                turn=false;

        }
        else
        if(cnt==4)
        {
            declare(pl2+" (Playing O) Wins!");
            String temp=pl1;
            pl1=pl2;
            pl2=temp;
            reset();
            if(vs==1)
            if(pl1=="Computer")
                compplay(val);
            else
                turn=false;
        }
    }
}

void declare(String stmt)
{
    if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,stmt+" Do you want to continue?","",0)!=0)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

void compplay(int n)
{
    boolean carry=true;
    if(diff==3)
        carry=winorstop(a,b,n);
    if((diff==2||diff==3) && carry)
    {
        if(n==1)
            carry=winorstop(c,d,4);
        else
            carry=winorstop(c,d,1);
    }
    if(carry)
            doany();
}

boolean winorstop(int l,int m,int n)
{
    if(pos[l][0]+pos[l][1]+pos[l][2]==n*2)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            if(play(l,i))
                return false;
        }
    }
    else
        if(pos[0][m]+pos[1][m]+pos[2][m]==n*2)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                if(play(i,m))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        else
            if(pos[0][0]+pos[1][1]+pos[2][2]==n*2)
            {
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                    {
                            if(play(i,i))
                                    return false;
                    }
            }
            else
                if(pos[2][0]+pos[1][1]+pos[0][2]==n*2)
                {
                        for(int i=0,j=2;i<3;i++,j--)
                        {
                                if(play(i,j))
                                        return false;
                        }
                }

    return true;
}

void doany()
{
    int l=2,m=0;
    switch(cnt)
    {
        case 0: play(0,0);
                break;
        case 1: if(!(play(1,1)))
                    play(0,0);
                break;
        case 2: if(!(play(2,2)))
                    play(0,2);
                break;
        case 3: if((pos[0][1]+pos[1][1]+pos[2][1])==val)
                    play(0,1);
                else
                    if((pos[1][0]+pos[1][1]+pos[1][2])==val)
                        play(1,0);
                    else
                        if(pos[0][1]!=0)
                            play(0,2);
                        else
                            play(2,0);

                break;
        default : while(!(play(l,m)))
                  {
                    l=rnd.nextInt(3);
                    m=rnd.nextInt(3);
                  }
                break;
    }
}


/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    label1 = new java.awt.Label();
    label2 = new java.awt.Label();
    label3 = new java.awt.Label();
    label4 = new java.awt.Label();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jCheckBoxMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();
    jRadioButtonMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem();
    jRadioButtonMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem();
    jRadioButtonMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem();
    jCheckBoxMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jLabel1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel1.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 10, 68, 69));

    jLabel2.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel2.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel2MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 10, 68, 69));

    jLabel3.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel3.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel3.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel3.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel3MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 10, 68, 69));

    jLabel4.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel4.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel4.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel4MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 90, 68, 69));

    jLabel5.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel5.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel5.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel5.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel5MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 90, 68, 69));

    jLabel6.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel6.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel6.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel6.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel6MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 90, 68, 69));

    jLabel7.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel7.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel7.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel7.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel7MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 170, 68, 69));

    jLabel8.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel8.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel8.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel8.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel8MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 170, 68, 69));

    jLabel9.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 60));
    jLabel9.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jLabel9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel9.setOpaque(true);
    jLabel9.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel9MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 170, 68, 69));

    label1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(label1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 161, 228, 6));

    label2.setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(label2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 81, 228, 6));

    label3.setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(label3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(161, 10, 6, 230));

    label4.setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(label4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(81, 10, 6, 230));

    jLabel10.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel10.setText("Player 1 to play First");
    jLabel10.setOpaque(true);
    getContentPane().add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 250, 250, 18));

    jMenuBar1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.darkGray);
    jMenuBar1.setBorder(null);
    jMenuBar1.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
    jMenuBar1.setFocusable(false);
    jMenuBar1.setOpaque(false);

    jMenu1.setText("Game");

    jMenuItem1.setText("New Game");
    jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

    jMenuItem2.setText("Exit");
    jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Options");

    buttonGroup1.add(jCheckBoxMenuItem1);
    jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setSelected(true);
    jCheckBoxMenuItem1.setText("Vs Computer");
    jCheckBoxMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jCheckBoxMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jCheckBoxMenuItem1);

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButtonMenuItem1);
    jRadioButtonMenuItem1.setSelected(true);
    jRadioButtonMenuItem1.setText("Easy");
    jRadioButtonMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButtonMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jRadioButtonMenuItem1);

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButtonMenuItem2);
    jRadioButtonMenuItem2.setText("Medium");
    jRadioButtonMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButtonMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jRadioButtonMenuItem2);

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButtonMenuItem3);
    jRadioButtonMenuItem3.setText("Hard");
    jRadioButtonMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButtonMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jRadioButtonMenuItem3);

    buttonGroup1.add(jCheckBoxMenuItem2);
    jCheckBoxMenuItem2.setText("Vs Player");
    jCheckBoxMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jCheckBoxMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu2.add(jCheckBoxMenuItem2);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    jMenu3.setText("Help");

    jMenuItem3.setText("How to Play");
    jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem3);

    jMenuItem4.setText("About");
    jMenuItem4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu3.add(jMenuItem4);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
   if(play(0,0)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(0,1)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(0,2)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(1,0)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(1,1)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(1,2)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel9MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(2,0)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel8MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(2,1)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jLabel7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if(play(2,2)&&turn==true)
        compplay(val);
}                                    

private void jRadioButtonMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    diff=1;
}                                                     

private void jRadioButtonMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    diff=2;
}                                                     

private void jRadioButtonMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    diff=3;
}                                                     

private void jCheckBoxMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    pl1="You";
    pl2="Computer";
    reset();
    vs=1;
}                                                  

private void jCheckBoxMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    pl1="Player 1";
    pl2="Player 2";
    reset();
    vs=2;
    turn=false;

}                                                  

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if(vs==1)
    {
        pl1="You";
        pl2="Computer";
    }
    else
    {
        pl1="Player 1";
        pl2="Player 2";
    }
    reset();
}                                          

private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"This is a  simple game  in which  Win  is achieved when\nthree consecutive blocks in a Row, Column or Diagonal\nare occupied before the opponent does the same.");
}                                          

private void jMenuItem4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Developer: Tejas Pathak\ndevtejaspathak@gmail.com");
}                                          

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup2;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem jCheckBoxMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
private javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem jRadioButtonMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem jRadioButtonMenuItem2;
private javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem jRadioButtonMenuItem3;
private java.awt.Label label1;
private java.awt.Label label2;
private java.awt.Label label3;
private java.awt.Label label4;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

I've been struggling for days now, Maybe you could run it on ur ide so you wont waste your time reading it all.. i've worked on this for a couple weeks.. Thanks for reading anyways... Wish you a good day. :)

Comment: see documentation of [setOpacity()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#setOpacity(float)): *"The following conditions must be met in order to set the opacity value less than 1.0f: ... The window must be undecorated"*

Comment: The error is clear: opacity cannot be changed on a decorated frame. Try calling `yourFrame.setUndecorated(true)` before changing the opacity.

Comment: also note that `AWTUtilities` was removed in Java 11: [Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8200149)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The "new" way of doing this would be here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: @keuleJ don;t tell me, tell the questions author...  I would use the `setOpacity()`, which the "old" method already used, and whose documentation I linked in previous comment (and probably is the same method used in the tutorial). I just wanted to *warn* the author that he eventually will have problems using that class.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks it helped can you put it as an answer so i can make it correct answer?